# Сбой зависимостей при создании проекта Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, nuget, .net-standard

[image]

Такая печальная картина наблюдается сразу же после создания проекта Xamarin.Forms с библиотекой .NET Standard 2.0. Общая библиотека не распознает ни одной зависимости.

Comment: Я не понял, разве .net standart должен что то знать о xamarin?

Comment: Видимо, должен, раз вижла таким образом проект создаёт

Answer (score 0):

Такое часто встречается. Вы загрузили готовый шаблон с кодом, но VS не успела все установить.
"Лечится" этими способами:

1. Подождите :-)
2. Перезагрузите VS.
3. Удалите кэш NuGet с компьютера и повторите все сначала.
4. Создайте проект с нуля постепенно добавляя пустые проекты и устанавливая руками нужные плагины.

Comment: просто VS обосралась. (жаль нет оффтопа, но термин самое то для таких случаев)